# If I know rank-$1$ matrix ${\bf x}{\bf x}^\top$, how can I find $\| {\bf x} \|_2^2$?

Tags: matrices, transpose

> If $A$ is a $3 \times 1$ matrix and
> $$AA^{T} = \begin{pmatrix}
>             1 & -1 & 1 \\
>            -1 & 1 & -1 \\
>             1 & -1 & 1 \\
>            \end{pmatrix}$$ what is $A^{T}A$?

---

I have tried, transposing both sides of the equation, $(AA^{T})^{T}$ , and transposing the matrix as well, but it doesn't give a 1x1 matrix. I am unsure of which property to use! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show us your effort.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CyclotomicField updated, any tips will be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following: Calculate
$$
(AA^\top)^2 = AA^\top A A^\top.
$$
Then observe that $A^\top A$ is a number and we can pull it to the front:
$$
(A^\top A)AA^\top
$$
So you just have to observe the common factor in $(AA^\top)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

The trace has the property that $\mbox{tr}(AB) = \mbox{tr}(BA)$. Therefore, $\mbox{tr} \left( A^T A \right) = 3$, and then

$$A^T A = (3)$$